# readfile doesn''t work for URL path

Tags: php, readfile

I used readfile to read the file but its not working for URL path. So, I gave the physical path for it. How to use URL path ?

```
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary"); 
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . basename($path) . "\""); 

readfile($path);
```

Comment: so in your case you need to change the readfile function to fopen if allow_url_fopen option is not on.

Comment: Thanks . Is this also a permission issue ??

Comment: That could be permission issue as well, but first this we should check is allow_url_fopen=On, if it is one then check for the permission, if still not working better to update code to use fopen rather than readfile.

Comment: does the answer of this question works for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If php.ini has enabled the option called

```
allow_url_fopen=On
```

Then url base path will work in readfile other wise you will have to use fopen.

Thanks
Amit